# How to animate Bitmap on Surface view onDraw()?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a game. I try to use GridView but wonder how can I drag Item onTouchEvent().  I found an example 
http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-ii,160.html

It is a great example. I cropped my image in 12 small image bitmap. display them on screen randomly on specific position.
By overriding the onTouchEvent() I got my requirement. Now I want to animate my image as the "swap" other image by animating. I have both images X,Y location. 
I am wondring if it can by done by some Animation class.So that I should not put effort for doing it manually. I know it is not a hard job. But I Animation class can do it more smoothly.
So I have a ArrayOfImages(Bitmap) and I want to swap 2Images with animation. I am using a thread that update "Canvas" in background. Please help me.
.
I more thing. How can I add Scroll view with surface holder?? Is it possible? Because I think when I try to drag my image , It my not drag and active scrollbar for this response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am using a loop for a specific x,y to a specific x,y while updating the canvas. Although this is not a efficient way.